# How to change Prometheus configuration scrape_interval for Prometheus deployment with Helm

Tags: terraform, config, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, scrape

I have Prometheus deployment with Helm and Terraform. On my Prometheus config page, it says that all my scrape_interval values are 30s.

[image: promConfig]

But, in my prometheus config file `/terraform/kubernetes/files/prometheus_config_map.yaml`, the scrape_interval is 15s.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'prometheus'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:9090']
- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component]
    action: replace
    target_label: job
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

And also the same in `/helm/charts/pulsar/templates/prometheus-configmap.yaml`

I feel like my Prometheus doesn't read the config from these files? As on the first screenshot, I have much more configuration than in my files here and scrape_interval is NOT the same. I also notice I have many files related to Prometheus under `/helm/charts/pulsar/templates/`:

[image: promConfig2]

And, also file `/helm/charts/pulsar/values.yaml`

[image: promconfig3]

Could you please let me know how I can change scrape_interval in this case? Thank you very much in advance. I would like to change scrape_interval, especially for kubelet job.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your Prometheus deployment isn't using the correct config file. Try to upgrade the existing installation with something like the following command in order to update the default Prometheus configuration with the one you want:

```yaml
helm upgrade your_prometheus_release --values your_prometheus_config.yaml stable/prometheus
```